# lazy loaded translations not working in ssr mode

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I recently added lazy loaded translations to my spartacus project and for the most part its working fine i can see json files being loaded in my network tab.

The only issue i am facing is in ssr mode when running in ssr mode i see in my node logs lots of errors relating to the json files

saying the following

```
An unknown http error occurred Http failure response for 
https://this-is-test:4200/app/spartacus/assets/translations/en/login.json: 0 Unknown Error
```

I tried chaning my load path as per spartacus docs to assets/18n-assets/en/login.json but its still the same.

I also tried adding the full load path to see if its a relative path issue but still the same.

Here is my configuration for lazy loaded translations, i am on spartacus version 4.3

```
provideConfig(<I18nConfig>{
 i18n: {
    backend: {
      loadPath: 'app/spartacus/assets/translations/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
    },
    chunks: translationChunksConfig,
    fallbackLang: 'en',
  },
}),
```

Comment: Could you please try to reproduce the issue with OOTB Spartacus app, using the latest 4.3.x patch version? I couldn't reproduce it locally, even using OOTB Spartacus 4.3.4. Perhaps the problem comes from some custom code in your project?

Comment: i can confirm, it was an issue to do with CORS/certificate

Comment: Would you mind sharing your solution in an _Answer_ and mark it as the most helpful answer, so the Spartacus community may benefit from your solution?

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't specify the exact Spartacus version you are using, I can only assume you are not using the latest one and blindly mention that you should upgrade to the latest 4.3.x, which contains fixes for the problem you are facing.

Basically, [this](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/14372#issuecomment-1059183669) comment explains the problem and links the two PRs which fixed the issue ([1st](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/pull/14453) and [2nd](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/pull/15297)).

Also, please make sure you have the following configuration in your `server.ts`:

```
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get(
    '*.*',
    express.static(distFolder, {
      maxAge: '1y',
    })
  );
```

EDIT: as pointed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74191870/lazy-loaded-translations-not-working-in-ssr-mode#comment131255650_74191870) comment, the issue is not present in OOTB Spartacus.
Can you please check your custom code? And perhaps double-check the `server.ts` file.